# What is the Lipschitz constant of a quadratic form?

Tags: quadratic-forms

Let $f(x) = -x^{T} A x$ for a positive definite matrix $A$.  Let the domain of $x \in R^N$ be in a compact ball (with radius > $\sqrt{N}$ if necessary)

What is the Lipschitz constant for $f$ in terms of (presumably spectral) properties of $A$?  Is it the maximum eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: In general, $f$ fails to be Lipschitz continuous (so there is no Lipschitz constant). For instance, consider the case where $A$ is $1 \times 1$ with $A = 1$.

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite, then the function $x \mapsto \sqrt{x^TAx}$ *will* be Lipschitz continuous; perhaps you are interested in this function instead.

Comment: Ah sorry, good point.   Yes, this isn't going to work for arbitrary quadratic forms.  But I am interested in the function itself rather than the squareroot.

What about the lipshitez constant for within a compact ball of `x` around the original?  Would that do it?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I added an additional change to the problem which hopefully makes it well defined.

Comment: @jperla See my answer below. Also, I was wrong: the square root fails to be Lipschitz over any neighborhood of zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any continuously differentiable function over a compact domain is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant equal to the maximum magnitude of the derivative.

The function $f(x) = x^TAx$ is differentiable with $\nabla f(x) = 2Ax$. It follows that over the ball of radius $R$, the Lipschitz constant of $f$ is equal to
$$
\max_{x \in B_R} \|2Ax\| = 2R\cdot \max_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|Ax\| = 2R\cdot \rho(A),
$$
where $\rho(A)$ denotes the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $A$ (the maximal **absolute value** among the eigenvalues of $A$).